# How can i assume that my date when has a value is equal to 1 and total?

Tags: jquery, date, sum, addition

**The date if has value i want it equals to 1 and add it all in total**

[image]

*heres my sample fiddle [My sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harvey2748/6uj3sayh/1)*

**html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('[id^=total]').on('change',function() {
        var total = 0;

        $('[id^=total]').each(function(index){

            total += parseFloat($(this).val()?$(this).val():0);
        });

        var totalAll = $('#amt_due').val(total.toFixed(0));

    });
});
```

Comment: Sebastian Mendoza do you want like this:-https://jsfiddle.net/oxjr78pf/

Comment: alive to die ur such a javascript lord hehe thanks a lot it works like a charm

Comment: glad to help you :):)

Comment: hey man i have some concern when im edit the date it keeps on adding the value of amount

Comment: check my edited solution

Comment: hey sir how could you do this your like a magician

Comment: ha ha ha. lot of praise,thanks. Btw i also start learning from 0 + some common  mistakes. I will recommend you to learn pure java-script (in depth) and try to understand its concept. If you become handy in java-script, jQuery is like a plaything to you. I face multiple time problem while using jQuery till now, because i never learn java-script in my learning days, now i am learning with coding only.

Comment: thanks man for your advice i work hard to be like yours hehe

Comment: wait sir when i do it to may project the value will be equals to 5 i think its because i use bootstrap calendar can you give me a sample that if only has a value not a specific type=date only

Comment: Now you have to ask a new question , because editing answer again and again is not right, because it's  ambiguous to future visitors (when they compare question with accepted answer).Thanks

Comment: yea thanks man ill go next question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343008/i-have-a-form-and-i-want-to-add-all-the-is-not-equal-to-zero hey sir this is my the another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want like this:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var total = 0;
  $('input[type="date"]').on('change',function() {
    if($(this).val() == ''){
      total -=1;
    }else{
        total = $('input[type="date"]').filter(function () {return !!this.value;}).length;    
    }
    $('#amt_due').val(total.toFixed(0));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='date' name='total[]' id='total1' value='' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='date' name='total[]' id='total2' value='' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='date' name='total[]' id='total3' value='' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='date' name='total[]' id='total4' value='' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='date' name='total[]' id='total5' value='' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="total_amt_due" id="amt_due" readonly="readonly" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```