# I have a form and i want to add all the is not equal to zero

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.4

[image: This] This is my desired output. I want the `date` will be equals to 1 and add in the total input and in class there's an additional x.

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('day1') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="day1" class="col-md-4 control-label">Day 1</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                           <div class='input-group date' id='day1'>
                              <input type='text' class="form-control" name="day1" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you ellaborate what you want please?

Comment: PLEASE ADD YOU INPUT+WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED SO FOR+WHAT YOU WANT EXACTLY+WHERE YOU STUCK.Only image is not going to help you

Comment: Share the relevant HTML, JS code, instead of the image.

Comment: Day2 has value and that is equal to 1 so the total is 2 because day 2 and day4 has a value

Comment: I think you want to loop through your forms with an integer that increases by one if form.value = 0 or whatever you're trying t count (you have 2 of each)

Comment: hey quys i have edit this sorry for lack of info

Comment: @PGCodeRider if i have a value that is not equal to zero that value will be 1 add it in total

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/harvey2748/oxjr78pf/1/ i also do like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I understand, you have different `input` fields and you want only those that have `values != 0`. You can use this pseudo code which traverses thru all `input` fields and your code will execute only if `value != 0`:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != 0) {
    // code goes here...
  }
});
```

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  updateCount();
})

function updateCount() {
  var count = 0;
  $("input:not('.k-textbox')").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 0) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  $(".k-textbox").val(count + 'x');
  console.log(count + 'x');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total1' value='0' />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total2' value='0' />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total3' value='0' />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total4' value='0' />
    </td>
  </tr>



  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="total_amt_due" id="amt_due" readonly="readonly" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: no man i want the  sum of the !=0 as one this looks like the sample result https://jsfiddle.net/harvey2748/oxjr78pf/3/

Comment: total and class is the same only additional x in class

Comment: I am unable to understand your requirements. And as I mentioned, its a pseudo code that you can tweak and use. I have updated the snippet too.

Comment: the sum will be insert in the total input

Comment: hey @milan this is actually i want to do but the type of input is date i want text https://jsfiddle.net/harvey2748/oxjr78pf/6/

Comment: Have you tried my code? input `type` doesn't matter, as the code is using `input` and not `type`

Comment: I have made minor change in the code, please check.